# Data table add column by column instead of row by row

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

```
col1    col2    col3
-----   -----   ----
1         4      7
2         5      8
3         6      9
```

Is there a way to build a datatable with the following way:

1. add column 1 as "col1"
2. add row for column 1 with value 1,2,3
3. repeat for next column and its respective rows

I was trying to begin with following codes but got stuck at second column and its rows

```
dt.Columns.Add("col1")
dt.Rows.Add(1)
dt.Rows.Add(2)
dt.Rows.Add(3)
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do better. What does the data look like before, so we can tell what you want to go where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've added columns and rows to your table, you can access the cells in each row by column index, which can be either a number or column name:

```
    dt.Columns.Add("col1")
    dt.Columns.Add("col2")
    dt.Columns.Add("col3")

    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())

    'Populate column 1 using index 0
    dt.Rows(0)(0) = 1
    dt.Rows(1)(0) = 2
    dt.Rows(2)(0) = 3

    'Populate column 2 using index 1
    dt.Rows(0)(1) = 4
    dt.Rows(1)(1) = 5
    dt.Rows(2)(1) = 6

    'Populate column 3 using column name as cell index for a change
    dt.Rows(0)("col3") = 7
    dt.Rows(1)("col3") = 8
    dt.Rows(2)("col3") = 9

    'Add and populate another column later
    dt.Columns.Add("col4")
    dt.Rows(0)("col4") = 97
    dt.Rows(1)("col4") = 98
    dt.Rows(2)("col4") = 99

    'Add and populate another row later
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow())
    dt.Rows(3)("col1") = 10
    dt.Rows(3)("col2") = 20
    dt.Rows(3)("col3") = 30
    dt.Rows(3)("col4") = 40
```